# signaling that unique_ptr is nullptr to classes using raw_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have underlying code. Is there a way to signal to the raw pointer that it's corresponding `unique_ptr` has been reset?

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pi = std::make_unique<int>(3);

int* rpi = pi.get();
std::cout << "rpi = " << *rpi << std::endl;

pi.reset();

if( rpi != nullptr) // this is always the case
{
    std::cout << "rpi = " << *rpi << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: raw pointers do not participate in ownership. If you want to share ownership you can use `shared_ptr` + `weak_ptr`

Comment: There Deleter function in [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), you can specify any Deleter function, implementing any kind of signal you want.

Comment: Why not just `.get` the raw pointer immediately when you need to do the test?

Comment: you can use deleter function, but how it would know where raw pointer values are? they are just that, values without ownership.

Comment: Instead of `if( rpi != nullptr)` just do `if(pi.get())` or even shorter `if(pi)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your raw pointer value may end anywhere in program, no you can't. Imagine that you would need some kind structure that contains a reference or pointer to a unique global variable created for your smart pointer. That variable stores state, not the "structure-pointer" you pass around. That it would work.

Now what's that structure is called in C++? It's `weak_ptr` and it takes its state from a `shared_ptr` only. Why? Because for any use of that pointer you have to claim ownership of it safely and that means shared ownership.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No, you can't.

But more importantly: You must not use the rawpointer after the reset!

When you call `pi.reset()`, the underlying deleter will be called. In your example this call will be equivalent to `delete rpi`. And as it is well known, after a memory address got deleted this way, you must not dereference it anymore.

In other words: This line

```
std::cout << "rpi = " << *rpi << std::endl;
```

invokes undefined behavior. If it does print the number 3, as you expect it to, this will be purely by accident. Your program might as well crash on this line or do literally anything else...

Answer (score 1):

Well, a kind of you can solve this task with some assumptions, using custom deleter functor. See code below, and explanations after code:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/fYTY3799n)

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class RefDeleter {
public:
    RefDeleter() {
        std::unique_lock lock(mux_);
        id_ = ++gid_;
    }
    ~RefDeleter() {
        std::unique_lock lock(mux_);
        refs_.erase(id_);
    }
    RefDeleter & operator ()(T * ptr) {
        {
            std::unique_lock lock(mux_);
            auto it = refs_.find(id_);
            if (it != refs_.end())
                for (auto e: it->second)
                    *e = nullptr;
        }
        delete ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    RefDeleter & AddRef(T ** ptr) {
        std::unique_lock lock(mux_);
        refs_[id_].insert(ptr);
        return *this;
    }
    RefDeleter & DelRef(T ** ptr) {
        std::unique_lock lock(mux_);
        refs_[id_].erase(ptr);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    uint64_t id_ = 0;
    static inline std::mutex mux_;
    static inline uint64_t gid_ = 0;
    static inline std::unordered_map<uint64_t,
        std::unordered_set<T **>> refs_;
};

static auto l = [](int* p) { delete p; };

template <typename T>
using ref_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, RefDeleter<T>>;

template <typename T>
class RefDeleterScope {
public:
    RefDeleterScope(ref_unique_ptr<T> & rup, T * & raw)
        : rup_(rup), raw_(raw) {
        rup_.get_deleter().AddRef(&raw_);
    }
    ~RefDeleterScope() {
        rup_.get_deleter().DelRef(&raw_);
    }
private:
    ref_unique_ptr<T> & rup_;
    T * & raw_;
};

#define GETRUP(raw, unique) \
    raw = unique.get(); RefDeleterScope ref_del_scope_##__LINE__(unique, raw);

int main() {
    {
        ref_unique_ptr<int> up;
        up.reset(new int(123));
        int * rp; GETRUP(rp, up);
        std::cout << rp << " " << (rp ? *rp : 0) << std::endl;
        up.reset();
        std::cout << rp << " " << (rp ? *rp : 0) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0x1182eb0 123
0 0
```

As you can see task is solvable with next assumptions:

1. Now you should use `std::unique_ptr<int, RefDeleter<int>>` everywhere instead of just `std::unique_ptr<int>`. I named first type `ref_uniqe_ptr<int>` for shorter convenience.
2. You can't use `int * rp = up.get();` but only `int * rp; GETRUP(rp, up);`, and you should use like this everywhere, first variant of usage will break solution. `GETRUP(rp, up)` assigns pointer of unique pointer `up` to raw pointer `rp`. As you can see `GETRUP()` macro assigns a separate cleaner class object that uses [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for cleaning-up after scope end.
3. This raw pointer `rp` now has a block lifetime, meaning that you can't copy `rp` outside its scope, meaning that you can't do `int * rp2 = rp;`, you should only do `int * rp2; GETRUP(rp2, up);`. Meaning whenever you need a copy of you raw pointer then you have to use `GETRUP()`. Because each new raw pointer is assigned a separate reference, that is updatable.
4. After reset all raw pointers will become nullptr. Even if you reset unique pointer to some non-null value still all referencing raw pointers will become nullptr. Only new raw pointers, created after reset, will hold non-null value. So my solution only clears raw pointers to null on reset, it doesn't update to new non-null value. If you want you can always reassign value of raw pointer if it became null by using `GETRUP()`.

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation but i think i should revisit my design.